# Where can I download free satellite imagery of Cambodia for offline use?

Tags: data, imagery, satellite

I am an entry level GIS user - I have had one semester of GIS in college.

I have successfully downloaded raster satellite imagery from Seamless (tiff files) for my class project.

Now I am trying to develope my GIS skills by volunteering with a non profit group that is doing environmental work with fishing villages in Cambodia.

I would like to download free satellite imagery of central Cambodia - similar to what I did with the Seamless data, to begin my geoprocessing project, any recommendations?

Comment: Great idea.  What do you wish to accomplish with the geoprocessing project?

Comment: Are you looking for Potential Fishing Zones (PFZ) in Cambodia... For PFZ you need to download Oceansat datasets not the landsat or any other.

Answer (score 8):

[Glovis](http://glovis.usgs.gov/) is one of the best places to start compiling free satellite imagery. For a new user, LANDSAT imagery is a great place to start - you will be able to find data covering the 1970's to present day. There is also a wealth of information available for working with this data. For example, if you are using ArcGIS you can quickly learn how to develop a [landcover map](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/05/28/classifying-landsat-image-services-to-make-a-land-cover-map/). [This page](http://gislounge.com/free-data-viewers/) lists some free data viewers that you may find useful.

Here is the [Quick Start guide](http://glovis.usgs.gov/QuickStart.shtml) to using GLOVIS.

Here is some [supplementary GIS data](http://data.geocomm.com/catalog/CB/datalist.html) specifically for Cambodia.

Even more Cambodia data in the form of an [interactive geographic database](http://www.yale.edu/cgp/maplicity.html). This one seems to focus on historical information, but does include free satellite imagery.

Answer (score 5):

List of all website providing free Satellite images available here on this site  http://www.indiaremotesensing.com/p/download-gis-data_6.html

Answer (score 4):

In this digital era there TONS of data out there. Some will be  useful for you other useful for others. - Define what you trying to measure, and what you need to measure it.

Check http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov , and its products. There are tons of scientific data expanding all over the globe.

Just to expand the answer a bit: You can find a list of the products with descriptions and Et cetera at https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/

Answer (score 4):

[Earth Explorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) would be a great place to look for satellite and aerial imagery along with data such as "Forest Carbon Sites".  A really interesting project would be to look at canopy cover change over the last 30 years using Landsat imagery.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may download such date from a service called [**LandViewer**](https://eos.com/landviewer). All the satellite data is **free** to use and easy to find thanks to the convenient search interface, which reduces time needed to find right image data. **[LandViewer](https://eos.com/landviewer)** has a list of default band combinations and spectral indexes for extracting information based on spectral signatures. You can also create your own **Custom** analytics. Standard tools for image enhancement in the Contrast stretching menu.

Here’s a brief guide to free satellite data that can be found on **[LandViewer](https://eos.com/landviewer)**:

- Landsat 4 - archive 1982-1993
- Landsat 5 - archive 1984-2013
- Landsat 7 - archive since 1999
- MODIS - archive since 2012
- Landsat 8 - archive since 2013
- Sentinel-1 - archive since 2014
- Sentinel-2 - archive since 2015

As an example, let's take a look at a satellite image of Cambodia. As you can see there are numerous images available for a deeper analysis.

[image]

https://eos.com/landviewer/?lat=11.71175&lng=104.98844&z=11&id=LV-TEMw-OF9M-MVRQ-XzEy-NjA1-Ml8y-MDE5-MDIx-MV8y-MDE5-MDIx-MV8w-MV9S-VA%3D%3D&b=Red,Green,Blue&anti&pansharpening